# Forcing overriden method to call base method implementation

Tags: python, polymorphism, subclass, python-decorators, metaclass

```
class Base:
    def method(self):
        print("Base method called")

class Derived(Base):
    def method(self):
        print("Derived method called")
```

I would like to find a way for the derived method to call the base method implementation automatically,or better yet, to force the calling of the base method **before** the derived method is called.

ex:

```
derived = Derived()
derived.method()
```

desired output:

```
Base method called
Derived method called
```

I wanted to avoid explicitly calling the base method inside the derived method.

I tried messing with `__init_subclass__` hacks:

```
class Base:
    def __init_sublcass__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        def wrapper(self):
            super().method()
            self.method()
        cls.method = wrapper
    
    def method(self):
        print("Base method called")
```

It works but pylance has problems with it and it's not really ideal or easy to understand.

Comment: Ah, you want the base method to essentially force itself to always be called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might force the `method()` to always call `Base.method()` using a metaclass.

How about something like:

```py
class Base_Meta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        def method_new(self):
            Base.method(self)
            cls.method_old(self)

        if cls.__name__ != "Base":
            cls.method_old = cls.method
            cls.method = method_new

class Base(metaclass=Base_Meta):
    def method(self):
        print("Base method called")

class Derived(Base):
    def method(self):
        print("Derived method called")

d = Derived()
d.method()
```

I think that will give you:

```
Base method called
Derived method called
```

Comment: just tried and it works. that was helpful. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you're conceptualizing this wrong. Rather than overriding the method and then forcing the child class to call the base class's method, split it into two different methods. The new method is intended to be overridden, and the original method enforces the ordering.

```
class Base:
    def method(self):
        print("Base method called")
        self.extend_method()

    def extend_method(self):
        pass

class Derived(Base):
    def extend_method(self):
        print("Derived method called")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a decorator which finds the correct base method and calls that before the regular one:

```py
def callBaseMethod(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        self, *rest = args
        base = getattr(super(self.__class__, self), f.__name__)

        base(*rest, **kwargs)
        f(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper

class Base:
    def method(self):
        print("Base method called")

class Derived(Base):
    @callBaseMethod
    def method(self):
        print("Derived method called")

def main():
    derived = Derived()
    derived.method()
```

Output as requested

Comment: My problem is that i didn't want to write anything else besides the derived implementation.
This way i would still have to specify the decorator.
This is just a fancy way to do `super().method()` before the derived implementation....
Thank you for the answer though, maybe I wasn't clear enough....

Comment: So, do you mean that only methods called `method` (or whichever you choose) should do this?

Comment: I don't understand your question... sorry @quamrana

Comment: I'm saying that if you are able to create a base class which does what you want, which of the derived class methods should behave as you want?

Comment: i would like for a particular method that i choose to have this particular behavior, that is, call the base method before calling the derived implementation.